# How to recover files from external hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, files, data-recovery, external-hdd

I was having trouble with Ubuntu so I installed Linux Mint. I was unable to sustain an internet connection with Mint so I re-installed Ubuntu 16.04. While Mint was on my computer, I uploaded over 600 photos that I also backed up onto two external hard drives. Now that I am running Ubuntu again I cannot find the photos that I put on the external hard drives while Mint was installed on my laptop.

The two USB hard drives still have everything that was there before Mint but nothing that was put there by Mint. Does anyone know how I can recover the files that were saved to external drives by Mint, now that I’m running Ubuntu?

Comment: Hold on, did you actually copy data to those drives? What does their partition scheme look like? It almost sounds like the data never got copied in the first place or failed while copying.

Comment: Consider adding a few other information bits to the question. How were you uploading photos (GUI, command-line, some specific backup software)? Are the USB connectors working properly ?  What filesystem types are on those hard drives ? Are the hard-drives in good health ?  You could consider trying a few data recovery software.